# Mount distant volume at startup with $ in the distant volume path

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

I can mount a distant volume using:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=username,domain=domain '//nasaddress/home$'  /mnt/point
```

I would now like to mount the volume at startup so that is shows up in the file explorer. I edited the /etc/fstab by adding the line:

```
'//nasaddress/home$' /mnt/point cifs x-gvfs-show,noauto,users,credentials=/path/.credentials 0 0
```

The volume indeed shows up on the left side of the file explorer, but when I click on it it displays:

```
mount cifs: bad UNC ('//nasaddress/home$')
```

I guess it's because of the quotes and the `home$`. How can I deal with this ?

Comment: I would try 1) remove quotes 2) remove quotes and `$` sign.